# Geometry nodes & raycasting sticky vertices

Tags: geometry-nodes, surface-deform

Preface: I'm pretty new to GN's and still figuring a lot of it out.

Something I am currently attempting to do is have a source geometry(think of this as a sticky patch) that is moved and stuck onto some target surface.

So we can move it around in free space but as soon as it comes into contact with the surface the patch sticks, currently it sticks but can freely slip and slide along the surface.

Ideally it should move around in freespace until it comes into contact with the target surface, then only movements in Z should have an effect, allowing one to remove it from the surface.

I'm half way there but need a helping push to get me over the finish line, I expect there are a few ways to skin this cat.

[image]

[image]